# Automatically expand Java directory structures in NERDTree

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Java by convention is pretty keen on directories. Because of this, all the code in my current Grails project is nested 5 directories deep, e.g....

```
~controllers
    ~com
        ~companyname
            ~teamname
                ~productname
                 |-[code actually here]
```

There's a similar folder structure under every core Grails directory (services, taglib, unit-tests), which means an awful lot of hitting o and j repeatedly.

Is there any clever way this can be automated and mapped to a key combination?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a clever way using NERD Tree help: `O` (shifted) recursively opens a node.

To know NERDTree key mappings, press `?` when in NERD Tree window.